# Migrating data with rake db:migrate does not change it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database-migration, dbmigrate

I am struggling with rails and db:migrate. I have a migration with this code

```
class SetDefaultInstallmentsForLicenses < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    License.where(code: 'LEADER').each do |leader|
      puts "Modifying license #{leader.id} with code #{leader.code}"
      leader.installment_available = true
      leader.installment_number = 5
      leader.save
      puts "After save #{leader.installment_available} #{leader.installment_number}"
      leader = License.find(leader.id)
      puts "After save #{leader.installment_available} #{leader.installment_number}"
    end
  end

  def down
  end
end
```

After running the migration there is this output

```
==  SetDefaultInstallmentsForLicenses: migrating ==============================
Modifying license 3 with code LEADER
After save true 5
After save f
==  SetDefaultInstallmentsForLicenses: migrated (0.0037s) =====================
```

It's clearly visible that the migration was executed, record was found, changed and saved, but after  reloading the record, the changes are not there.
What's wrong?

Comment: You should do `puts leader.save`, to really know if save was successful.

Comment: leader.save returns true

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
  leader.save
  puts "After save #{leader.installment_available} #{leader.installment_number}"
  ==> After save true 5
```

Above is only showing the value of `installment_available` and `installment_number` fields from `local variable leader`, it is NOT pulling the value from database. **This does not mean that the fields were successfully saved in database.**

```
  leader = License.find(leader.id)
  puts "After save #{leader.installment_available} #{leader.installment_number}"
```

BUT the above is fetching the record from database and clearly shows that the updates were not saved in the database.

Instead of `leader.save`, use `leader.save!`. This way if record was not saved then you will know exactly why it was not saved because of the raised exception .

**UPDATE**

As per OP's answer given on this question

> I tried to put
>
> License.reset_column_information
>
> before the code and it seems to be
>   working now. I don't have clue why this is needed here. All my other
>   migrations seem to be working properly.

I did little bit of research what exactly `License.reset_column_information` did. I found **[Using Models in Your Migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#using-models-in-your-migrations)** which says:

> *When using a local model, it's a good idea to call Product.reset_column_information to refresh the Active Record cache
>   for the Product model prior to updating data in the database.*

Hope this helps you to understand why `License.reset_column_information` was required.

Comment: Lol... they deleted this from the documentation. No wonder it took me forever to find WTF, Rails.

Comment: In my case, `save!` did not raise an exception even though the column failed to update. Also, you can use `leader.reload` instead of `leader = License.find(leader.id)` to refresh the record from the database.

Answer (score 3):

I tried to put

```
License.reset_column_information
```

before the code and it seems to be working now.
I don't have clue why this is needed here. All my other migrations seem to be working properly.

Comment: See my Updated answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that it's been saved. I'm not. Place:

```
puts leader.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
```

after `leader.save` string